# Ignore lines matching a pattern when linting in Atom

Tags: package, atom-editor

I want to lint my markdown document using [linter-write-good](https://atom.io/packages/linter-write-good).

However, I don't want to see Errors in markdown quotes. Is it possible to ignore some lines (e. g. when starting with `>`)?

So this should be linted:

`- Everything builds on something done before. Strictly speaking, nothing is original.`

But this should not:

`> Every new idea is just a mashup or a remix of one or more previous ideas.`

Although both lines are in the same file.